# Ontology - How do we describe actions/scenarios in relation to objects?

Tags: logic, ontology

Does anyone know how actions to do with objects are represented in ontology or first order logic?

Example: the cat sits on the mat.

I think the cat and mat have properties that relate them to each other. The cat has a "sitting on" relationship with the mat, and the mat has a "being sat on" relationship with the cat.

But how do we represent the "sitting" scenario itself? The cat sitting on the mat doesn't seem to be a property at all?

Thanks

Comment: [States of affairs](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/states-of-affairs/) are one option.

Comment: Sitting-on is a relation between two objects, it is represented by a 2-place predicate S(x,y) = "x sits on y", so this is represented as S(Cat,Mat). Properties are represented by 1-place predicates, they are not involved here.

Comment: @Conifold kristianberry. no not the property or relation I mean the event of the cat walking up to a mat and sitting in it in. Is this possible?

Comment: In FOL is a binary relation: "x sit on y".

Comment: Describing change and events requires [temporal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/), it is much more involved than the standard first order predicate calculus.

Answer (score 1):

We can add events to our ontology to handle cases such as you describe. In your comment you speak of a cat walking up to a mat and sitting on it. This could be represented by saying there exists an event x such that this is an event of a cat walking to a mat, and then there exists an event y which is an event of the cat sitting on the mat. If the cat is called Felix and its mat is called Matty, then this could be written:

```
(∃x)(Walks(felix, matty, x)) ∧ (∃y)(Sits(felix, matty, y))
```

Adding events to our ontology in this way was championed by Donald Davidson in a series of papers published in the collection: Essays on Actions and Events, Oxford: Clarendon Press (1980). In particular, he was concerned to be able to represent adverbs in logical terminology. For example, "John ran quickly" entails "John ran". To represent this in first-order logic, we can treat the event of running as a thing in order to ascribe the property of being quick to it.

```
(∃x)(Running(john, x) ∧ Quick(x))
```

and this straightforwardly entails:

```
(∃x)(Running(john, x))
```

As you might guess, adding events to our ontology is controversial, and is not accepted by those philosophers who prefer their ontology to be as parsimonious as possible. There has also been much discussion concerning the status of events, their nature, how they are individuated, whether mental events should be understood as different from physical ones, how events relate to the concepts of causation and time, etc. There is some further information in the Stanford Encyclopedia entry on [Events](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/events/).